# Pathfinding with decisions

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

Consider the following (finite) map:

```
P░b▓░░░░G
░░░a░░░░░
░░░▓▓▓▓▓▓
░░░B░A░░░
░░░░░░░░░
```

Where `P` and `G` are the Player and the Goal, respectively. `a` and `b` are gates that can be opened (turned to walkable nodes) by pressing switches `A` and `B`. Only one switch can be used. `░` are walkable nodes and `▓` are walls.

How would you approach this problem? Obviously simple heuristics (A*) would not do as you have to decide which switch to use. My only solution was to bruteforce the whole thing - recursivelly trying every path & every switch along it (as long as no switch has been used before). This works, BUT as I mentioned before, it's brute force which means that the time complexity is enormous.

The question is: **can another algorithm do better? If so, how does it look like?**

*(I tried to search for a related question, but found nothing. Sorry if this is a possible duplicate.)*

Comment: If there are only few switch-gate pairs (say K), consider their every possible configuration (2^K in total). Between changing states of switches, a simple BFS would do. The overall complexity would be S * 2^K where S is the size of the map (witdh * height).

Comment: I thought of that, but the number of switches is arbitrary (can be a huge number) plus some can be placed somewhere the player can't reach. That would overcomplicate the issue as you would have to check whether the switch itself is reachable and how far is it. I should have specified this before - the map is only the simplest example.

Comment: If only one switch can be used, there are k, not 2^k choices, no?

Comment: If your lab is random, no way; if it has some structure you may then use that structure to direct the path finding algorithm. Tell us more about the labyrinth structure. What do you know? Location of gates? switches? A "filling" algorithm must be better than a path-finding.

Comment: AFAIK there is no structure. If what you say is true, brute force is the best option then. By the way: how would you implement switches in filling algorithm such as A*?

Comment: Do you need the shortest possible path, or just any path?

Comment: At the very least, you can make a graph of interesting points (start, finish, switches and gates), compute their reachability and distance from one another in polynomial time, and then run whatever search you come up with on the graph, not the whole labyrinth. Note that, in this graph, two points may be unreachable directly, but reachable via an intermediate vertex (gate) once it's open.

Comment: If any path will do, we can simply switch all switches until there are no more reachable, then go to the goal if possible. This will get the problem solved in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one switch can be used in the process, you can solve the problem in `O(W*H)`.

Start with a *BFS* from `P` position, after that if `G` was reached then you finished, otherwise for each gate(`k`)-switch(`K`) you reached,  continue the *BFS* from `k` position (of course, you can't pass any other gate).

Continue the process until you reach `G` or handled every gate. Note that you must process only the gates that reached in the first *DFS* (started from `P`), not for the *DFS* of the gates, and any gate `k` is walkable in the corresponding *BFS*, not during other *BFS*s.

Since all positions are visited at most once, time complexity is `O(W*H)`.

Comment: Doesn't that make the complexity O(k*W*H)? (k being the number of switch-gate pairs)

Comment: @ViliX64: No, because each switch-pair are actually nodes of the map, so counts any step of the BFS, and you don't have to start the BFS from scratch, you can use the same visiteds array for all BFS, so you will visit on each BFS only new nodes (those that are accessible from that gate) not entire map.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the explanation.